VREF for MAX31865 design
I am designing a circuit with the MAX31865 RTD IC, and I am reading the pin description of the DVDD and VDD pins. The datasheet states that these two pins should be connected to a 3.3V power supply.
However, from previous experience with EMC testing, if the 3.3V power supply becomes noisy, then it can affect ADC readings since Vref is influenced.
The datasheet of the IC has a functional block diagram on page 9 which shows that the BIAS pin is connected to the VDD pin, and later it is stated that BIAS should be connected to REFIN+, which I am guessing is the reference voltage.
Therefore, I am considering connecting a REF35 IC (Vref IC) to VDD instead of a 3.3V power supply, as it should keep a more precise and steady reference voltage for the MAX IC.
Has anyone tried this before and do you see any reason why one would not do this?

It's not unusual to have a separate analog supply bus to control noise issues.
I'm assuming here that you are supplying everything in the typical application diagram from the series reference IC and that the latter is getting sufficient input voltage (eg. 5V) to properly regulate. Noise rejection will be better if there is a bit more headroom than the minimum. Also, in general, pay careful attention to the chip bypass capacitance (must be sufficient) and what the reference IC will tolerate while remaining stable- references are not necessarily designed to have large capacitive loads.
Note that the absolute value of the voltage is not as important as the noise, since RTD measurements should be ratiometric, so that particular reference IC might not be optimal. You might be able to use an ordinary LDO (or even a passive filter) instead.
However you do have to consider what happens if (or when) your analog supply is present when the digital is not present and vice-versa. You might want some series resistors on the digital lines that cross supply boundaries. It's less of an issue with an I2C interface, but that appears to be an SPI type.

What made me aware of this question is this article. So to me it seems more relevant to have a stable voltage reference than a LDO that might not deliver let's say 3.3V exactly.

When you are measuring voltage the magnitude of the reference voltage is very important. When you are measuring an RTD the reference voltage cancels out since the current is determined by the reference voltage. In fact, if you have a separate very stable reference for an ADC and it's not what determines the RTD current you actually make things worse accuracy-wise than if you have an inaccurate drifting single LDO!

Ok, so if I understand you correctly, it could be a smart design choice to add an IC such as the REF35 for an ADC to provide stable REFIN voltage when doing single-ended voltage measurements? But if one were to measure RTD with the same ADC, it would be a better choice to use a LDO?

The REF35 is fine for both (assuming the adequate headroom, copacetic capacitive loading  etc.) but it may be unnecessary for the RTD situation. I'm not sure if the REF35 has any disadvantages (other than cost and possibly availability) compared to an LDO you might be using already elsewhere- but I mentioned a couple possibilities above.  Note the output stable capacitive range is 100nF to 10uF and the ESR must be in the range of 10mΩ to 400mΩ - go outside that and some samples could oscillate under some load, line temperature conditions - a thoroughly nasty problem to debug.

Alright, thanks for the feedback.
